# Recommended value for NoDriveTypeAutorun?

Tags: windows-registry, virus, autorun

The **AutoRun feature** of Windows can be controlled through the Registry by tweaking these values:

```
Current User:   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun
Local Computer:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDriveTypeAutorun
```

By tweaking individual bits (see [explanation](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-enable-disable-nodrivetypeautorun.htm)) we can control different types of drives:

- Disk that can be removed from the drive (such as a floppy disk or USB
  flash drive)
- Disk that cannot be removed from drive (usually a hard
  disk)
- Network drive
- CD/DVD drive
- RAM disk

I have been setting this to zero to avoid infections by malwares, from whatever source. This simple setting can have a tremendous impact on the number of infections people contract on their computers.

My question is: if I do this in friends' computers (or co-workers), **what positive functionality could they be missing?**

1. Plugging mobile network cards might not work until they ran their setup manually;
2. CD-ROMs with digital content might not work until they ran their setup manually;
3. ...?

I think most people would be able to get their work done without Autorun, but I would like to hear your facts / informed opinions / real-world stories that could **help me reach a recommended value** for this setting.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  `AutoRun` is disabled from `Windows 7` and greater by default.  The feature speaks for itself.  By default Windows won't do something chosen by the user automatically if `AutoRun` is disabled.

Comment: I'm running Vista, I didn't mention it because I was looking for a generic answer. I didn't know what you wrote in your comment regarding Windows 7 (and newer), so that's at least part of the answer... thanks

Comment: A generic answer for Windows registry hack that is a horrible idea.  Update your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no positive functionality they would be missing by having AutoRun disabled. AutoRun is just a feature that makes it easy for less technical users to easily and quickly perform some tasks related to the USB device. If the user is not totally clueless about how to use a computer, AutoRun should be disabled. This should be the case in any business environment. Of course doing this will not guarantee safety (nothing can). If oyu haven't heard of [BadUSB](https://srlabs.de/badusb/), you don't know what USB drives are capable of.